# How do i make this button stick on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, button

When I click on this button the button disappears. im trying to make it so the button sticks on the screen and always adds one to the money variable. (sorry for the unclear explanation)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var money = 0;
            function addMoney() {
                money += 1;
                document.write("Money: <b>" + money + "</b>");
            }
        </script>
        <button type="button" onclick="addMoney()">Get a money</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's unclear, what you are asking.

Comment: This question is extremely ambigous. For instance, why would increasing the value of money add a button, and where do you intend to write this bold element money from?

Comment: Please do not close the task as **"Needs details or clarity"**. The task is very clear.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov It wasn't, *until you edited the unclear language and put words in the mouth of the OP to fit your answer*.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I agree. I just want save this question, since this problem is not unique :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand exacly what you want to do. But if you want to print the money variable on an element as you click the button, you can try:

```html
<script>
  var money = 0;

  function addMoney() {
    money += 1;
    //document.write("Money: <b>" + money + "</b>");
    document.getElementById('money-div').innerHTML = money;
  }
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="addMoney()">Get a money</button>
<div id="money-div"></div>
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks a lot that is exactly what i wanted! sorry for the weird explanation i was in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `document` so you won't see your button after clicking. You do the rewriting this way:

```
document.write("Money: <b>" + money + "</b>");
```

Create an additional container for entering values into this content:

```
<div class="count">Money: <b>0</b></div>
```

And declare this content as a selector and then assign the value on click:

```
document.querySelector(".count b").textContent = money;
```

```js
var money = 0;
function addMoney() {
    money += 1;
    document.querySelector(".count b").textContent = money;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="addMoney()">Get a money</button>
<div class="count">Money: <b>0</b></div>
```